# Expression Parameter is not displayed in generated Swagger documentation

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a `Controller` that has has a parameter of type `Expression<Foo, bool>` with the name `query` however that parameter does not show up in the generated `swagger.json` file. Instead a lot (>1000) parameters that have names like these show up:

- `Body.CanReduce`
- `ReturnType.IsGenericMethodParameter`
- `Type.IsGenericType`

I would like to tell `SwaggerGen` to have my parameter just shown up as a string. If it is possible using a Filter, that would be my preferred way, but an Attribute would be fine too.

I already tried using an `IOperationFilter`, but it did not work as `operation.Parameters` does not even seem to have a paramater with the name `query`.

```
    private static readonly Type _expressionType = typeof(Expression);

    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        foreach (var parameter in context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.Parameters)
        {
            if(_expressionType.IsAssignableFrom(parameter.ParameterType))
            {
                // The parameter is found ...
                var expressionParameter = operation.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == parameter.Name);
                if (expressionParameter != null)
                    Debugger.Break(); // ... but is not in the operation.Parameters collection although the >1000 mentioned above are.
            }
        }
    }
```

P.S. to anyone interested: I'm using a custom ModelBinder and `System.Linq.Dynamic` to parse a query string to an `Expression<Foo, bool>`

Comment: Have you tried with an IDocumentFilter?

Comment: A DocumentFilter is way too late. At that point these >1000 Types are already in the document. I'm looking for some way to filter these out before that is even generated.

Comment: To be clear an IDocumentFilter will work ... but if you want to do it before the only other option I see it to change the parameter to string and do the parsing in your code.